# How to get the text from the selected cells in a table view?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

I am unable to get the multiple selected rows text into an array by using checkmark searched in stack overflow but unable to implement it can anyone help me how to get the text in an array ?

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return productName.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "filterSelectionCell", for: indexPath) as! FilterSelectionCell
        activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
        tableDetails.isHidden = false
        cell.brandProductName.text = productName[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){
        if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath) {
            if cell.accessoryType == .checkmark{
                cell.accessoryType = .none
            }
            else{
                cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
            }
        }
    }
```

here is the image for that

[image]

Comment: Get the data from the data source (**model**) rather than from the cell (**view**). Add a `selected` property to the model and set the accessoryType in `cellForRow` accordingly. To get all selected cells just filter the data source array by `selected == true`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my answer with the below code you can delete the selected strings from the array which you had appended previously in the array

```
var values = [String]()
var selected: Bool

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){
        selected = false
        if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath) {
            if cell.accessoryType == .checkmark{
                cell.accessoryType = .none
                print("\(productName[indexPath.row])")
                values = values.filter{$0 != "\(productName[indexPath.row])"}
                selected = true
                print(values)
            }
            else{
                cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
            }
        }
        if selected == true{
            print(values)
        }
        else{
            getAllTextFromTableView()
        }

    }
    func getAllTextFromTableView() {
    guard let indexPaths = self.tableDetails.indexPathsForSelectedRows else { // if no selected cells just return
    return
    }

    for indexPath in indexPaths {
        values.append(productName[indexPath.row])
        print(values)
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [indexPathsForSelectedRows](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614864-indexpathsforselectedrows) property of the UITableView

You will be able to get all the indexPaths of selected rows and then integrate over the array of these indexPaths and fetch your texts from your dataset (productName array in your case).

Like this:

```
fun getAllTextFromTableView() {
  guard let indexPaths = self.tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows else { // if no selected cells just return
    return
  }

  for indexPath in indexPaths {
    print("\(productName[indexPath.row])") //Here you get the text of cell
  }
}
```

Of corse you need to have @IBOutlet to your table view in order to access it in the function.

Comment: I need to get the elements in an array how to get it as an array ? @Sergey Pekar

Comment: got it no need but if I uncheck how to delete it from the array ? @Sergey Pekar

Comment: Atlast I got it for delete also thanks bro @Sergey Pekar

Answer (score 0):

You should use an array of product objects instead of an array of names for your table's data source.  Each product would have a name and a Bool value to say whether it's selected or not.

Finding the selected products would then be a easy and -- more important -- you wouldn't be using the UI as your data model to learn whether something was selected.